# Alternate to this sql query that will return rows having 0 documents

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there any alternative to the following query which will return me records having zero documents??  Please help me.

SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( Order By ParentID ) AS RowNumber_ps, UPPER(HostApplicationLocalData.ParentID) asParentID, COUNT(Document.ID) as Documents FROM HostApplicationLocalData LEFT OUTER JOIN Document ON HostApplicationLocalData.ID=Document.HostApplicationLocalData_ID WHERE HostApplicationLocalData.TransactionType_ID = 1 AND (Document.Removed=0 OR Document.HostApplicationLocalData_ID IS NULL) AND HostApplicationLocalData.Company_ID = 9000 AND (SharePointURI is not null or ((SharePointURI isnull and Content_ID is not null ) or ((HostApplicationLocalData_ID is not null andHostApplicationLocalData_ID != 0 and Content_ID isnull)) ) ) GROUP BY HostApplicationLocalData.ParentID )q WHERE Documents = 0

Comment: How about some fomatting & aliases? And no syntax errors.

Comment: Can you show me plz?

Comment: Click 'edit' under your question; highlight/select code; click '{}', add returns & indentation etc.